# Ubuntu 20.04 no WiFi adapter found

Tags: wireless

I already used my HP Omen 15 for ~6month everything was fine with WiFi,
but just today I turned it on and I've bumped into no WiFi adapter found (maybe there was done some software updates, but i am not sure).

kernel version `5.4.0-58-generic`

Only one OS is installed, Ubuntu 20.04.

`$lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

```
    DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] [8086:0034]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

`$dmesg | grep iwlwl`

```
[    5.145197] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    5.155453] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    5.155456] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug configuration: 0
[    5.155789] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.6bf1df06.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.254185] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9560, REV=0x318
[    5.262513] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    5.263617] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    6.287705] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 15 fired.
[    6.536747] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
[    6.536763] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[    6.536771] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC9CA680F | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    6.536779] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    6.536788] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD783DAFC | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    6.536796] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    6.536804] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xFCBEF554 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    6.536813] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x628A6667 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    6.536821] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xEFEB5813 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    6.536829] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x7669DD66 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    6.536838] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    6.536879] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    6.536952] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    6.537026] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    6.537229] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0xa5a5a5a2, CPU2 Status: 0xa5a5a5a2
[    6.537230] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[    6.537270] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
[    6.550005] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

`$sudo lshw -C network`

```
*-network                 
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 10
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:ba21c000-ba21ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3c:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 16
       serial: b0:0c:d1:63:3c:24
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:bc304000-bc304fff memory:bc300000-bc303fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:4
       logical name: usb0
       serial: 0e:45:8a:f7:7e:c5
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.165 link=yes multicast=yes
```

`$lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 10)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #21 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #14 (rev f0)
00:1d.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #16 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM470 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP106BM [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile 6GB] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02)
03:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02)
03:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02)
03:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02)
3a:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 USB 3.1 Controller (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02)
3b:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp WD Black 2018/PC SN720 NVMe SSD
3c:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 16)
3d:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

`rfkill list all` empty

```
$dmesg | grep -i firmware
[    0.110318] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    1.166501] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[    5.155789] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.6bf1df06.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.263617] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    6.537270] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
```

i`ve tried to reinstall:

```
sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Is there something that can help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it a dual boot with Windows?

Comment: no Windows on a laptop, only one Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bcmwl-kernel-source
I suggest the following:

1. Uninstall `backport-iwlwifi-dkms` and `bcmwl-kernel-source`.

The latter is completely unrelated, because it is a Broadcom driver.

2. Boot with a previous kernel using grub menu.

Comment: i uninstalled those libs and have switched to Linux 5.4.0-56-generic. Same thing. No wifi adapter.   iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110

Comment: It is either a hardware problem, or a kernel bug. But if it doesn't work on both kernels, it's unlikely a bug. Is `dmesg | grep iwl` same with this kernel.

Comment: You can try to install the 5.8 kernel by `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04-edge`.

Comment: i`ve installed 5.8 kernel, with all kernels
[    7.021288] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110